# Toggle two fields with one animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get an information tag to slide out from behind a circular picture. In order to do this I used a block and circle to create the information field and stuck it behind the image.

The problem I am running into is getting it to slide out smoothly. Since there are two div's, the square slides out and then the circle, causing it to look choppy.

I would like to get it to toggle in and out as if it were one object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.employeeBlock').hide();
    $('.employeeDot').hide();
    $('.employee').click(function(){
        $('.employeeDot').toggle('slide');
        $('.employeeBlock').toggle('slide');
});
```

I have tried it with the employeeDot inside the employeeBlock which is in the employee div
as well as both the employeeDot and the employeeBlock seperate and in the employee div.

Both methods give similar results

Thanks

EDIT: Thanks for the replies, it's running smoother, but not quite perfect. I think I need to create one item that is shaped like a bullet, and toggle that in and out. Any ideas on how to do that?

The closest I can get is a pill shape, which leaves some of the area uncovered

EDIT: Here is my html:

```
    <body>
        <div class = 'employee'>
            <div class = 'employeeDot'></div>
            <div class = 'employeeBlock'></div>
            <img class = 'pic' src = "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQfMDb1Qtu7gTDZTfnFR2XcPqrfkn27zeWASTBfczi-GGQAIKG_"/>

        </div>      
   </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

> .pic {
>    height: 150px;
>    width: 150px;
>     border-radius: 75px;
>     position: absolute;
>   }

```
>.employeeBlock {
background-color:maroon;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
position: absolute;
left: 75px;
float: left;
```

}

```
>.employeeDot {
background-color: maroon;
height: 150px;
width: 250px;
border-radius: 150px;
position: absolute;
float: left;
left: 75px;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.toggle();` is deprecated, use `.slideToggle();` instead.

Slide down:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.employeeDot','.employeeBlock').hide();
    $('.employee').on("click", function(){
        $('.employeeDot, .employeeBlock').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Slide from side:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.employeeDot','.employeeBlock').hide();
        $('.employee').on("click", function(){
            $('.employeeDot, .employeeBlock').animate({width: 'toggle'});
        });
    });
```

Comment: slideToggle makes it come in from the top be default, it there a way to adjust this?
Also, the .toggle('slid') was working fine, the problem was that I was using two different items and it was a little choppy

Comment: You want it to slide from the side?

Comment: I have updated my answer, if you could provide html it would be helpful.

Comment: The .animate() is working perfectly, thanks. I am assuming the {width: 'toggle'} part makes it toggle between 0 width and it's full width. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure because I have personally never used it, but I believe it toggles to either the width of the element or the width of the container.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single result:

```
$('.employeeDot, .employeeBlock').toggle('slide');
```

[Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: Thanks, but this makes it so the square and circle start sliding at the same time, but there is still a space between the two during the transition.

Comment: You want when one finish the other starts?

Comment: I would like it to toggle as one big item. I tried to clarify what I am looking for in the edit.

Comment: Not exactly. I need the final item to be a bullet shape, so that when it sits behind the original circular picture, it forms one big pill shape

Answer (score 2):

The rest of the answers have covered everything, but to get the element to shape like a bullet use:

```
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
```

But match the size and sides to your likings.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.employeeBlock,.employeeDot').hide();
$('.employee').click(function(){
    $('.employeeDot, .employeeBlock').toggle('slide');});
```